# Generalisation of $\Gamma$ function?

Tags: gamma-function

Let the incomplete $\Gamma$-function be defined as:
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(c+1,x)=\int^\infty_x t^ce^{-t}dt
\end{equation}
Is there a well studied generalisation of the incomplete gamma function that would work when the R.H.S is
\begin{equation}
\int^\infty_x f(t)\ e^{-t}dt
\end{equation}

Comment: Consider the Laplace transform of $f$ with a time delay.

Comment: Is your function has the Laplace transform ?

Comment: If you have no constraints on $f$ at all, then a general theory would not be able to say anything very interesting, because it would need to handle every $\int_x^\infty g(t)\,dt$ by setting $f(t)=g(t)e^t$.